# VHDL timing simulation for a CPLD using Quartus Prime and Modelsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

I am developing a design (*VHDL*) for an *Intel Max II CPLD* used on a development board for testing. Later this will most likely be replaced by a *Coolrunner II CPLD*.

I am pretty new to this.
Basic compilation and simulation using *Quartus Prime Lite* and *Modelsim* works fine. My current design looks like this:

```
-- The top level entity used for synthesis.
entity foo is
  port(...)
end foo;

architecture rtl of foo is
  ...
begin:
  ...
end rtl;

-- The top level entity used for simulation producing some test input signals.
entity foo_tb is
end foo_tb;

architecture behave of foo_tb is
  ...
  component foo is
    port (...);
  end component foo;
begin:
  UUT : foo
    port map (...);
  ...
end behave;
```

Looking at the resulting (RTL) simulation, i could not spot any signal delays which would be there on real hardware, just the behavior i had specified in the `architecture behave of foo_tb` and `architecture rtl of foo`.

But i had expected the compilation process to do synthesis and afterwards to generate some *VHDL-Code* containing something like `architecture <some_name> of foo` for simulation purposes, which models the behavior of the real hardware with worst case timing behavior considering the synthesis.

1. Is such VHDL-Code generated?

If such VHDL-Code is generated:

2. Where can i find the produced *VHDL* files?
3. How could i use it from within the `architecture behave of foo_tb`

If such VHDL-Code is NOT generated:

4. how can i do simulations using a detailed timing model of my design which results from the concrete synthesis on a specific *CPLD*?
5. How could i programmatically produce input signals for such a simulation?
6. How could i programmatically check for correct output signals of such a simulation?

Comment: Did you look for documentation? Did you read it? I'm sure Quartus provides tutorials.

Comment: Yes, there are step by step tutorial to do things like this. But they do not explain for what each step is good for. And the Quartus Documentation could not be worse in this regard. All i can do is guess and ask. The best tutorial i have found so far is this one: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa10/cse140L/lab2/Lab2_tutorial_timinig_simulation.pdf . But i can't get it to work in combination with a Testbench driving the simulation. And i do not know whether this is best case or worst case behavior or which kind of delays are considered and which are not.

Comment: Concerning questions 1 to 3: You might like to search the project folder for new VHDL files. If you find some, check their contents. -- And then Quartus should offer some user support. Did you try to contact them?